# How can I create a sankey plot with Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio, sankey-diagram

I'm working on a google data studio dashboard...
I'd want to add a sankey plot but I can't find the way to do that.

I found this page that explain something [[link]](https://www.blog.google/products/marketingplatform/analytics/introducing-data-studio-community-visualizations-developer-preview/)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Community Visualization - Sankey Diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534969/how-to-use-community-visualization-sankey-diagram)